# PSpice model 1SMB5914BT3G temperature coefficient

Tags: ltspice, zener

I'm simulating a circuit with a on-semi 1SMB5914BT3G zener-diode (3.6V) using LTSpice. If I increase the temperature from 27°C to 47°C the zener voltage increases from 3.6V to 4.26V @100mA.

[PSpice Model from onsemi](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/1SMB5914BT3G.LIB)

Isn't that far too much? If I have a look at the [datasheet page 4](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/1SMB5913BT3-D.PDF) I would expect approx. -1.5mV/°C. Is there an error in the spice model or am I using it wrong?

[image: Simulating 1SMB5914BT3G with LTSpice]

Comment: Sounds too high. Who made the model?

Comment: @winny It's from the official onsemi website and has this in the header "*      Model Generated by MODPEX     *
*Copyright(c) Symmetry Design Systems*"

Answer (score 1):

Run the model with a current source as shown below and you will likely get the results you expect.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa49WT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This doesn't even use the linked spice model, right?